# when i change ImageButton image , not changing at real-time

Tags: java, android, sleep, imagebutton

i use this code for change `ImageButton` image , but it not change at real-time.

it change one time only , not `ImageButton` by `ImageButton`.

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= left_num ; i++ ){
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("c"+i+"_r"+right_num, "id", this.getPackageName());
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_circle);
    sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably changes "in real-time", but you're not able to see it because the line of code `sleep(500)` is ignored and does not do what you expect it to do.

**Edit:**

You can set a Timer to update the ImageButtons sequentially by calling the method below:

```
private void updateImageButtonsSequentially() {
    int iteration = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("c"+iteration+"_r"+right_num, "id", this.getPackageName());
              iteration++;
              ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
              imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_circle);
        }
    },0,500);
}
```

Comment: i want to pause it some time to see the changes

Comment: You might want to use a Timer to execute the code inside your `for` loop every 500ms.

Comment: شكراً لك , أفدتني كثير